# How is this if block being executed in this imported file?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, execution

I have an `index.js` file (entry point in my react app) that imports 2 named exports from another file like so:

`import { funcA, funcB } from './myFuncFile`

and in `myFuncFile` I have an if statement at the top like so:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "local") {
   // do some stuff
}
```

this might be a silly question but how is that if statement being called?

I assumed I'd have to import the whole file like:

`import * as myFun from './myFuncFile`

to get the if block to work? is the mere fact I'm just importing it, causing the if block to execute?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. When the file is imported as a whole, then this line will be triggered when the exported statements are loaded into memory.